# Domain Events for confirming state

Tags: c#, wcf, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I have a question about Domain Events.  I am implementing an application using DDD and yes the application is complex enough for DDD.

The scenario I have is a Login Wcf Service, besides validating the User credentials and returning a Token the service is required to create a Session and Audit the Login.  For this I have created two separate Domain Context for the Session and Audit as these are outside the scope of the Login I intend to raise domain events to handle these within their own Domain Context, all this is good and keeps clear bounded contexts between each component.

The question is, part of the Wcf implementation is in a SharedKernel as is required by all Wcf Services to handle token validation of the Token that needs to be passed to the Wcf Service from the Client for security.  The validation of the Token requires checking that a valid Session exists (eg. There is a record in the database with the same Token and has not expired), I am struggling with how best to implement this and have some thoughts

1. I believe that since the Session is in its own Bounded Context that I should raise a Synchronous Domain Event that returns the result, after all I only need a true/false confirming that there is a valid Session for the Token
2. or; I could implement a Domain Context just for this in the Shared Kernel to handle this, however this would mean having Domain Entities and EF Contexts in the Shared Kernel and potentially outside the Bounded Context of the Session.

I am really struggling with which is the best approach, has anyone encountered anything similar and what would be your advice for implementing this with best practices? Are Domain Events the right approach for what I need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you *may* be making this more complicated and harder than it needs to be :)

One typically has an **Identity & Access Control** Bounded Context for these types of things.  Well, *I* would certainly put them all together in there.  This BC has very little to do with your domain model so one could think of it in terms of a supporting role.

A *synchronous* domain event probably isn't quite the correct naming either.  You certainly may need a synchronous call though.

All this interaction would take place at the application service layer and your domain should not have to dig into any of the lower infrastructure type bits as it is moving along.  Instead pass in the domain-based representations into you domain if you need to use the values.

What I have used in the past is to simply log in the user, create the session, and audit the session as a single task.  Other downstream systems would make a call to the central **I&A** endpoint (rest api in my case) to retrieve the session VO for the specified token.  Although you may only need a `true`/`false` confirmation currently you may end up with a bit of interesting data on your result such as `Upn` for impersonation, `Claims`, `ExpiryDate`, etc.  The downstream system knows when the session will expire so it is quite possible to cache the session for frequent requests.  A *system event* could be published from the **I&A** BC should a user explicitly log out.  This would allow the downstream system to subscribe to, say, the `SessionEndedEvent` message and remove the cached session.

Just as a side not: I have started approaching domain events differently from messaging-based events (a la service bus) as I find *domain events* contain less information than that which is available at the application service layer where *system events* can be generated.  This is probably why domain events fit in so nicely with event sourcing.